# How can I keep two files in sync within the same repository?

Tags: windows, git

My repository in git looks like this:

```
-Project Repo
    -Sub Folder 1
         -File 1
         -File A
    -Sub Folder 2
         -SubSub Folder
              -File 2
              -File B
```

File 1 and File 2 are exact copies and rather than manually sync them, I'd like to do that automatically with git. At the same time Files A and B are not the same and I do not want them to be sync'd across. Is it possible to keep to files in sync in git?

Comment: Just curious: _Why_ you need duplicates?!

Comment: Could you make File 2 a symbolic link to File 1?

Comment: @ghbarratt how would I do that?

Comment: Depends on your operating system. If you're on linux (or other unix), have a look at `man ln`.

Comment: @svick no such luck, I'm on windows

Comment: Yes, as dmedvinksy says, mklink might be worth a shot. It will depend on whether git will treat a windows symlink like we want it to .. but I just tried this:

    `C:\Users\ghbarratt>mklink help_file_upload.php E:\work\help_file_upload.php`

and now I see the link in C:\Users\ghbarratt and can open or edit it like the original file.

Comment: @ghbarratt I'll give it a try, why don't you add that as an answer?

Comment: I meant to mention that I did that in Windows 7.. and if it works for you then maybe I will throw it in an answer and you can accept it. :-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully a symbolic link is all you need.

If you are in Linux/Unix you would issue the symlink creation command as follows:

```
cd ".../Project Repo/Sub Folder 2/"
ln -s "../Sub Folder 1/File 1" "File 2"
```

In a version of Windows that support symbolic links, you can try the mklink command:

```
cd ...\Project Repo\Sub Folder 2
mklink "File 2" "..\Sub Folder 1\File 1"
```

Comment: It seems that git doesn't transfer the symbolic link when the files are pushed to the server and then fetched/pull, but I think this will work, each developer will just need to setup the symbolic link on his/her computer. It might be best to include a batch or something. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing things on windows, I assume you are using Visual Studio. What I have done in the past is used pre-compile steps in the project properties to copy the file over from one location to the other. The copy of the file in the new location is explicitly ignored so it won't get committed.

Comment: Most development tooling has something similar.. What are you using?

Comment: Programmers Notepad 2 primarily for PHP and JS