# Keep two files in sync in the same SVN repository?

Tags: linux, svn

Very similar to this question: [Sync two files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798564/how-can-i-keep-two-files-in-sync-within-the-same-repository), but using svn instead. Is there any way other than using a symlink or adding a step to the build? I was hoping for svn modules, or svn copy, but if it's really impossible, I don't want to spend a lot of time on it. This is a Linux based environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [svn externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html), but the purpose of externals is not to clone individual files in the same repository. You might find it a little bit slow and clumsy for this purpose.

Comment: as stated in the provided link, externals definition can only point to directories, not files

Comment: @Vladimir, sorry, got an old link to svn externals. From SVN 1.6 externals is working on files too. I updated the link to the correct version.