# Tools for convenient viewing of Tomcat 7 logfiles

Tags: tomcat, logging, tomcat7, monitoring

Is there any software (except [Psi-Probe](https://code.google.com/p/psi-probe/) and [Java Melody](https://code.google.com/p/javamelody/)), which allows to look in the Tomcat files and is more comfortable than `cat /var/log/tomcat7/catalina.out | tail | less` ?

Ideally, it would work like this: I launch the application (or open a web page) and immediately see current log file of Tomcat (without the need to open the SSH client, entering credentials etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for centralized log management take a look at [logstash](http://logstash.net/).
Another solution is [Octopussy](http://www.octopussy.pm/).

Both tools can be configured so that you only see the logs of a specific server. Those tools are not Tomcat-specific, you can use them also for retrieving logs of your database server, web server etc.

Answer (score 6):

Use a symbolic link to map the log file to a text file in the [document root](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html).

In Windows:

```
mklink %DOCUMENT_ROOT%/tomcat.txt %TOMCAT_LOGS%/tomcat.log
```

In *nix:

```
ln -s $TOMCAT_LOGS/tomcat.log $DOCUMENT_ROOT/tomcat.txt
```

Open the log in the browser:

```
https://127.0.0.1/tomcat.txt
```

**References**

- [How can I keep two files in sync within the same repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798564/1113772)

Comment: The Windows version is wrong. The link file should be the first parameter, and the target file, the second one. 
Works great, anyway.

Comment: @JuanCalero Fixed. Happy to help

Comment: Note that, if implemented like described, this will **make your logs available without authentication**. For a public-facing Tomcat, this is probably not what you want... though you can mitigate the problem, for example with a restrictive reverse proxy.

Comment: The biggest disadvantage of this is that you have to refresh the page each time there is activity. But still, I like the creative solution :)

Comment: soft link (ln -s ... ..) does not work on linux installed tomcat-8.x. Instead you should create hard link to catalina.out